# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 881999 into shape (2)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pathlib

I trying to run this code but, showing an error like this. what should i do, can any help me

this is he code that i tried (In windows)

```
from pathlib import Path

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile as wavfile
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter

def db_fft(data, sample_rate):
    data_length = len(data)
    weighting = np.hanning(data_length)
    data = data * weighting
    values = np.fft.rfft(data)
    frequencies = np.fft.rfftfreq(data_length, d=1. / sample_rate)
    s_mag = np.abs(values) * 2 / np.sum(weighting)
    s_dbfs = 20 * np.log10(s_mag)
    return frequencies, s_dbfs

audio_file = Path('1500.wav')
frequency, data = wavfile.read(str(audio_file))
data = data[0:4096]
x_labels, s_dbfs = db_fft(data, frequency)
flat_data = savgol_filter(s_dbfs, 601, 3)
plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
plt.figure(dpi=150, figsize=(16, 9))
plt.semilogx(x_labels, s_dbfs, alpha=0.4, color='tab:blue', label='Spectrum')
plt.semilogx(x_labels, flat_data, color='tab:blue', label='Spectrum (with filter)')
plt.grid(True)
plt.title(audio_file.name)
plt.ylim([-160, 0])
plt.xlim([10, 10000])
plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude [dB]')
plt.grid(True, which="both")
target_name = audio_file.parent / (audio_file.stem + '.png')
plt.savefig(str(target_name))
```

the error showing like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File
"c:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Ismail\sample.py", line 19, in <module>
frequency, data = wavfile.read(str(audio_file)) File
 "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\scipy\io\wavfile.py",
line 689, in read data = _read_data_chunk(fid, format_tag, channels,
bit_depth, File
 "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\scipy\io\wavfile.py",
line 490, in _read_data_chunk data = data.reshape(-1, channels)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 881999 into shape (2)
```

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Can you share your file? Maybe you have only one channel and metadata is wrong (2 channels). Try to convert your wavfile to mono.

Comment: Because `wavfile.read` usually has no problem reading a `.wav` file, my finger is pointed towards your file. Likely it's either corrupted or malformed.

Comment: The factors of 881999 are 19, 61, and 761. I don't think your file has 19, 61 or 761 channels. Of course it could still be a MONO file, but then you should know better than me, shouldn't you?

Comment: actually this i done in ubuntu and its works perfectly even with this same wav file but when trying to run this code in windows its showing error like this

Comment: @Corralien Yes its stereo channel, so can help me to edit the code that also support stereo wavfile

Comment: Try to use another package like [python-soundfile](https://github.com/bastibe/python-soundfile).

Comment: If the file is EXACTLY the same on both platforms, report a bug. `md5sum` is your friend on Ubuntu, don't know about Windows.